# How to instantiate a WinMD file to a Windows Store App Project

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-rt

Hi have an Windows Store App that need to reference a single Winmd file.
I've added it adding as a normal DLL, that's the correct way?

**As my understanding I'm trying to "instantiate" it on my default.js as below:**

```
var helloTest = new WinJS.HelloWR.HelloRT();
```

**With that I'm able to access its methods as:**

```
var ret = helloTest.helloRt();
```

**The problem happens when I try to run it, it raises the following exception:**

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'HelloRT' of undefined or null reference
```

It means that my HelloWR namespace is undefined, I've been looking around google for some similar sample but I've found anything.

Let me know if anyone need more info about the content of this **winmd**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those whom faces the same problem, I just did as below:

```
var helloTest = new HelloWR.HelloRT;
```

It's not needed to put WinJS as the question at the Top.

Now I'm able to access its methods:

```
var ret = helloTest.helloRt();
//ret returns 'HelloRT'
```

If someone explain it better I will check as answer.

Comment: WinJS it just a namespace that's defined in the WinJS libraries. You only use it when you are using something from that library. Similarly, the Windows. namespace is used for WinRT. When using your own WinRT component, however, you use whatever namespace is defined for that component itself, e.g. HelloWR. You can see this in the WinRT component samples and documentation on dev.windows.com.

Comment: Thanks for the complements @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT